# Apache Karaf CXF jax-rs services using declarative services and karaf-assembly

Tags: rest, jaxb, cxf, karaf

this is a complex configuration question
I have a sample project here (develop branch)-> 
https://github.com/gadieichhorn/play.karaf.calculator/tree/develop

I packaged the features and used the karaf-assembly artifact in attempt to create a custom karaf distro with my project already deployed.

so far I can deploy the feature/kar on my local karaf but when I create a custom karaf assembly the cxf REST service is not working.

The packaging process is automated:
build -> feature/kar -> assembly -> integration tests (pax-exam) -> docker -> acceptance.

```
2016-09-12 02:14:52,245 | WARN  | qtp18647439-126  | AbstractJAXBProvider             | 40 - org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs - 3.1.6 | javax.xml.bind.JAXBException

 - with linked exception:

[java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory not found by cxf-dosgi-ri-dsw-cxf [13]]
```

```

Here is my feature dependencies:

```
<feature>scr</feature>
<feature>aries-rsa-core</feature>
<feature>cxf-jaxrs</feature>
<feature>cxf-dosgi-provider-cxf</feature>
```

here is my assembly:

```
        <configuration>
            <startupFeatures>
                <feature>eventadmin</feature>
            </startupFeatures>
            <bootFeatures>
                <feature>minimal</feature>
                <feature>shell</feature>
                <feature>shell-compat</feature>
                <feature>aries-blueprint</feature>

                <feature>scr</feature>
                <feature>aries-rsa-core</feature>
                <feature>cxf-jaxrs</feature>
                <feature>cxf-dosgi-provider-cxf</feature>

                <feature>calculator</feature>
            </bootFeatures>
        </configuration>
```

my REST service API

```
@Component(
        name = "org.play.karaf.calculator.proxy.root",
        service = {ProxyRoot.class},
        property = {
            "service.exported.interfaces=*",
            "service.exported.configs=org.apache.cxf.rs",
            "org.apache.cxf.rs.httpservice.context=/calculator",
            "org.apache.cxf.rs.address=/proxy"
        }
)
public class ProxyRootProvider implements ProxyRoot { ...
```

My model is still JAXB implementation which supposed to by the default provider for CXF. do I need to add providers?

I tried with:

- Karaf 4.0.5 & 4.0.6
- CXF 3.1.6 & 3.1.7
- Aries 1.8.0. & 1.9.0
- DOSGi 1.8.0

what am I missing from the assembly stage to make the distro work?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in  features: cxf-dosgi-provider-**cxf** must be cxf-dosgi-provider-**rs**

Also compare libraries in karaf_home/lib/endorsed in your custom karaf assembly and default distribution of karaf. 
If it not the same, add to your configuration all endorsed libraries.

For example:

```
    <libraries>
         <library>mvn:org.apache.servicemix.specs/org.apache.servicemix.specs.jaxp-api-1.4/2.8.0;type:=endorsed</library>
         <!-- ... other libraries -->
    </libraries>
```